# Вопрос по реализации PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Как это можно реализовать? Цвет не обязателен. 
Уже имеется база с оценка учениками. Я только 1 не могу понять, как вывести оценку именно под этой датой. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала формируем массив с датами ($dates).
Потом формируем другой массив:

```
$users['ФИО']['Дата'] = оценка;
```

Потом формируем таблицу:

```
$t = '<table>';
$t .= '<tr>';
$t .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
foreach($dates as $date){
    $t .= '<td>'.$date.'</td>';
}
$t .= '</tr>';
foreach($users as $fio => $null) {
    $t .= '<tr>';
    $t .= '<td>'.$fio.'</td>';
    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $t .= '<td>';
        $t .= !empty($users[$fio][$date]) ? $users[$fio][$date] : '&nbsp;';
        $t .= '</td>';
    }
    $t .= '</tr>';

}
$t .= '</table>';
echo $t;
```

как то так.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!